# Finding residue with respect to closed path

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be the closed path consisting of straight line segments from $2+2i$ to $-2-2i$, from there to $-2+2i$, from there to $2-2i$ and finally back to $2+2i$. Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ for each of the following functions giving reasons for your answers.

I know how to use the residue theorem and I know how to find the residues. My question is on the closed path. I'm not used to integrating on this sort of path. How will this path affect my index? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you describe is equivalent to two separate triangular contours, left and right.  Left is negatively oriented (i.e., clockwise) and right is positively oriented, i.e., counterclockwise.  So you simply split your integral up into two separate integrals, one for each triangular contour.  Each of the triangular contours is simple, so it has index of one, as usual.